# wordpress login loop and session problem

Tags: login, session

I have a login problem in the Wordpress Admin panel.

First I have the redirect loop wp-admin to wp-login with the param reauth=1.

I tried all the suggestions found in the support forums but none of them worked for me (clear browser cookies, delete plugins, themes, htaccess file, define siteurl in wp-config ...). 
The site was moved to https can that cause the issue ?

Second I have some kind of a session problem ? when I go to a page from a completely different browser in a different device, I find myself logged in with the last login I was trying to use in the first browser? it's like it keeps the last login in memory, this is a security problem because any user can be logged it to the admin panel...

I have never experienced this problem before, does anyone have an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: When you say the site was moved to https can you be more specific? That could mean several unrelated things, e.g. did you just turn on HTTPs and redirect everything at the server level? Did you do a search replace of the database? ( if so how? ) Did you change `wp-config.php` options? Did you just install one of those SSL plugins? Did you move to a new host? Do you have caching? Please be specific not just about what you did but how you did it, even if you don't think it's relevant, and if you don't know something or aren't sure, please say so

Comment: Hello thank for your answer, I just turned on HTTPS and redirected everything.
The issue was solved finally by simply disabling the server's cache for the admin page.